# How to override default keyboard layout?

Tags: android, keyboard, dynamic

My Android app has several EditText widgets in various input languages- i.e. field "1" is strictly English and field "2" is strictly German

As far as I know, it is impossible to directly change the keyboard language. However, is it possible to override certain keys to both look and write different characters (i.e. 1->ą and etc) depending on the EditText field id / settings / type or other?

As all the words are names / company names the autocorrect feature is not necessary.

Comment: what platform/operating system?

Comment: I'm developing for Android. 

Thanks for comment :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the keyboard language programmatically, but discouraged. I imagine the discussion in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks:) 

Is it possible to simply replace both the label and the associated action for each key individually, rather than system on the whole?